# Pycharm attach to process inside a container causes accept timeout

Tags: docker, pycharm

I am using pycharm professional 2021.3.1 and ubuntu 18.04
I can attach to any process running directly on the host

However if the process is running inside a container (no matter what host privileges' I gave it)
I cannot attach. I get the following error
"Connection to python debugger failed Accept timeout'

I Tried on another computer and got the same results

Is this a known issue? Are there any work arounds? Except for using remote debugger (which requires adding extra code to the production code)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, it is not documented (as far as I can tell) but since it is for debugging only I will continue with it

Pycharm Professional set the IDE like you would for remote debug server
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config

In the docker file of the containers that you wish to debug always install:

1. gdb
2. pydevd-pycharm

After the container and the process is up go into the container and run

"python3 /usr/local/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py --port port_set_in_pycharm --pid pid_of_process_to_debug_in_container_id --host ip_of_the_host_running_the_pycharm"

the following is the same command pycharm uses when you do attach to process

now you can put breakpoints and debug normally

Advantage of this solution in contrast to remote debug defined in the pycharm documentation is that we do not have to add code to the production code